# Define an empty area in the head of my layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating my screens for my android app, for that I created a background image. In the background is a header area which should not be covered by my app. Actually this is my problem, my linear layout starts directly in 0/0 position. How can I define that I have for example 30 px of empty space in the head of my screen.

Thanks

Comment: Set the top padding value for the `Linearlayout` to the desired dimension.

Comment: For best results, break the image into 2 and use two image views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the property `android:paddingTop="30px"` to the container which has the background. 
By the way, you should avoid using pixel and you should use dp instead.